# Can I attach a string to a Func in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

I'm looking to create named functions: objects that act as `Func`, but also have a string field containing a human-interpreted name.

The natural approach would be to make a class `NamedFunc<T0,T1> : Func<T0,T1> { string name; }` but unfortunately Func is not a class. So I'm looking for a workaround.

The end goal is that I have a function which DoMethod(MyObject victim, Func<T,T> op) and inside DoMethod I would need an alphanumeric representation of `op` (for caching and compatibility reasons). Currently I use `op.toString().hashCode().toString()` but I'd like something more meaningful, so that I can actually see which file belongs to sum, square, etc. instead of just seeing 8202589252, 58809258520, etc.

For example, I want to pass to DoMethod something along the lines of `NewFunc<double,double> square = new NewFunc<double,double>(x=>x*x , "square");` and then when calling `DoMethod(victim, square)` DoMethod would somehow be able to recover that this function's string is "square" instead of "Func<double,double> x => x * x". At the same time, I want people to be able to just use regular Func as an input as well (without overloading the method).

Is there any feasible way to do this? Or am I looking for something impossible?

Comment: This is unclear to me, However maybe you just want a dictionary of delegate/func ?

Comment: Map the funcs with a dictionary?

Comment: _"am I looking for something nigh impossible?"_ -- depends on what exactly you want, which isn't clear at the moment. You absolutely cannot _inherit_ a delegate type. But there are lots of other alternatives. See e.g. [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Delegates also store the target method, so you could use the name of the method from that. Or you could wrap the delegate in another delegate that returns both the result of the invocation and a string, as a tuple. Or...well, there are plenty of possibilities. You just need to figure out what you actually want.

Comment: Decorator patterns would be perfect, but according on that Wikipedia page, the C# part still uses inheritance, which is not possible here? Perhaps I'm missing the point, but indeed I would only need to decorate Func.

Comment: Yeah, you'd still have to wrap it for propper decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although as you said, you can't use inheritance since `Func` is not a class, you can still use composition:

```
public class NamedFunc<T, R> {
    public string Name { get; }
    public Func<T, R> Invoke { get; }
    
    public NamedFunc(Func<T, R> function, string name) {
        Name = name;
        Invoke = function;
    }
    
    public static implicit operator Func<T, R>(NamedFunc<T, R> namedFunc) 
        => namedFunc.Invoke;
}
```

And you will be able to do what you want:

```
NamedFunc<double,double> square = new NamedFunc<double,double>(x=>x*x , "square");
```

To get its name, simply do `square.Name`. To call it, simply do `square.Invoke(someNumber)`.

Comment: Nice solution; the question remains...why? If you look at the question, they want to pass the reference to the named function while also calling it? Now, what would be the benefit of that?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Is it _that_ weird to know the name of the function passed in? Also it seems like in this case it doesn't even need to be the method's name. My understanding is: any string will do, because OP is currently using `op.toString().hashCode().toString()` and it doesn't seem to matter. OP seems to just want to associate _some_ string to delegate, creating a delegate-string pair.

Comment: I mean, it's pretty weird considering the name is basically meaningless until they force it upon themselves. I agree, it's probably good enough to put any random string in there which, again, makes me wonder what the benefit is. Wouldn't you have to then conjure up that random string at some point in time for it to be useful? My question is still why; just curious.

Comment: Say I use their example and do something obvious and compile-time safe: `square.DoSomething(victim, nameof(square));`. Not terrible; but what if that's not the case. Any consumer of this could just as easily do `s.DoSomething(victim, "foobar");`. It's hard to see the meaning or benefit of the added restriction on calling a method you already wrapped up. So either, you already know the potentially secret string holding the gate keys or you don't at which time everything fails. Maybe I'm over thinking it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm not understanding what you mean. Assuming `s.DoSomething` is `DoMethod`, the second argument of that should be a `Func<T, R>`, not a string. What's this "secret string" that you are talking about? Nothing is secret here? Regarding "the name is basically meaningless until they force it upon themselves", I would imagine it is used for debugging (among other things), which is why OP wants it to be human readable, rather than just `op.toString().hashCode().toString()`.

Comment: Meh, I messed the example up, it's too late to edit it, and I'm not that concerned about it.

Comment: I've added my rationale for wanting human readable names for it instead of hashes (this didn't seem very relevant to me, but seems I was wrong to think that), and they can't be simply the function's .toString() because that's not allowed in file names (and you don't want x/y and x*y both mapped to the same file, so just removing the illegal characters isn't a solid choice either). Interesting construction though, never seen this `implicit operator` used in that fashion, will have a look into that. Thanks either way!